# jquery load dialog MVC 4 modal empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im working on an application in ASP.Net MVC4
The idea is to load a partial view into a modal dialog, the partial view is an image visor, here's the code(when I load the partial into the jquery dialog):

```
function cargarEmergente(codMovimiento) {
        var url = '/Autoservicios/BcrExpedienteFuncionario/DetalleMovimientos?codMovimiento=valor';                     
        url = url.replace("valor", codMovimiento);

        $("#modalMovimientos").load(url).dialog({
            height: 'auto',
            maxWidth: 1024,
            minWidth: 840,
            position: ['middle', 70],
            modal: true,
            closeText: 'Cerrar' 
        });
    }
```

Detalle Movimientos is a controller method by the way...
Works like a charm in Firefox,Chrome and IE 10,9,8 but in IE7 the modal dialog where the partial view is supposed to be loaded is empty.

Here's the controller method:

```
 public ActionResult DetalleMovimientos(int codMovimiento)
    {
        var movimientoSeleccionado = new BcrMovimiento {CodMovimiento = codMovimiento};
        var archivosMovimiento = _movimientoArchivosModels.ConsultarPorMovimiento(movimientoSeleccionado);
        var movimientoArchivoses = archivosMovimiento as IList<IMovimientoArchivos> ?? archivosMovimiento.ToList();
        var count = movimientoArchivoses.Count();
        if (count > 0)
        {
            var listaImagenes = movimientoArchivoses.Select
                (archivo => new BcrMovimientoArchivos {Ruta = archivo.Ruta}).ToList();

            ViewBag.codMovimiento = codMovimiento;

            return PartialView(listaImagenes);
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("<h2>El movimiento seleccionado no contiene archivos adjuntos.</h2>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. `load()` is a GET request and you may be seeing a cached result. 2. Does the version of jquery you are using support IE7?

Comment: We are using the one that comes for default with ASP MVC4: 1.8.2
I'll check out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself when we removed the trailing commas in another script our view was using!
It seems one failure in just one script was messing the whole page.
Thanks!